# (2.9.1) Grease pencil stroke points automatically connecting to other points

Tags: error, grease-pencil, 2d

This may be user error, so any suggestions would be much appreciated...

I am using Blender 2.9.1 to do 2d illustration, using grease-pencil stroke.
Whenever I draw a stroke and view it in object mode, it seems that points along the stroke have been automatically connected to random other points on the drawing. In addition, if I try and make a copy of the stroke, the copy carries over the same random connected lines as part of the drawing.

I've used 2.8.3 and have not had this issue before.

Here are some images for reference:

Stroke in Edit Mode:

[image: Drawing in Edit mode]

Stroke in Object Mode:

[image]

Stroke object copy, with random lines included in stroke:

[image]

Comment: Hello, this isn't a default I'm aware of. Are you using a material with a fill? It might just be you're seeing the filled "loops" here?